# Need help converting html code into XpathQueryString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I was following raywenderlich's tutorial on how to parse html into xcode and it works when it comes down to his website.However, the only problem now is I seem to not grasp the concept of Xpathquery.All I want is the table data.This is the html code below.

```
<div>
 <table class="detail-view" id="yw0"><tr class="odd"><th>ID</th><td>kick</td></tr>
```

I thought the code below would work, but it didn't. Any help will be appreciated

```
 NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//table[@class='detail-view']/td";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to extract from the table; but I'm going to infer that it's the element `<td>kick</td>`.  In that case, using the following source:

```
<table class="detail-view" id="yw0"><tr class="odd"><th>ID</th><td>kick</td></tr></table>
```

and an XPath query string of:

```
//table[@class='detail-view']/tr/td
```

I get a result of:

```
Element='<td>kick</td>'
```

Perhaps you could use [this tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to tune your queries.